ImportError: cannot import name 'DefaultHttpxClient' from 'openai'
How can I resolve the error "cannot import name 'DefaultHttpxClient' from 'openai'" when trying to import from the openai library?
openai -- 1.23.6
I want to create a custom API proxy to utilize the functionalities of the openai package

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
